# C# coding for inherited class set — is it a good practice to use keywords 'base.methodname and this.methodname'?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, this, radix

I have been working in C# for quite some time but come around this perennial question with colleagues now and then.

The question is: In an inherited class set -- when calling a method should we use keywords 'base.methodname and this.methodname'... irrespective of whether it is a overridden method or not?

My answer is: YES -- its a good practice -use it because that is why those were created for.

Detailed explanation: Moreover the code is likely to undergo changes in terms of logic and maybe some IF-ELSE like conditions may come-in at a later date. So at that time, the developer has to be compelled to revisit each line of code and ensure that he/she makes the right choice of which method is being called --- base.methodname() or this.methodname() ELSE the .NET framework will call the DEFAULT (i think its base.methodname()) and the entire logic can go for a toss.

What do other C# programmers think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not you use "this." is a matter of opinion. Some like it because it is clear that you are calling something class level, others feel it is redundant noise.

As for base - in my opinion you should only explicitly say "base." if you want to call the base method explicitly and not an overridden method in the current class. Quite often the only place you should even see it is in the overridden method itself.

*Don't* call base just because it is the implementation in the base class that will be called. It is **not** meant to be a way of saying "I know the actual implementation is in the base class", it is meant to be a way of saying "specifically **do not** call the implementation in this class, call the base one". To use it in any other way partly defeats the point of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you will always use the method in base class, you can use base.MyMethod. 
But be aware of this:

Imagine that you have a method called "GetPrice" in base class and you start using base.GetPrice all over your inherited class (PromoClass). After 3 months someone asks to change the way that price is calculated in Promotions (PromoClass), you (or the new developer) will override or new the method and test it... wait, don't work :|. Because you are always calling for the method in base class. So it will still call the method in base and you need to change all calls in the class.

It's an example of course. If that is standard in your company everyone should know that he should change all over the class the call of that method, if not, be careful.

I prefer to use "base." to use base methods but I normally ignore the "this.".

Answer (score 0):

I think it smells like bad class design if you in any way could be in doubt whether you are calling a method in a class or a base class.

It is hard for me to find any good examples that would justify explicitly calling overridden base class methods, expect if deriving from legacy or third party classes.

Personally I almost never use virtual methods. You can almost always make a better design with interfaces and abstract methods.

When using base calls it is because you want to extend the functionality of the base method, so you call the base method in the overriding method. Any other usage of base is in my opinion wrong in every way. Also, before overriding a virtual method and calling base you should consider if the extension could be implemented otherwise. For example, if your base method called an abstract method or an interface method that you could either implement or inject in the derived class.

The few times I have used virtual methods are when leaving "blank" methods in a general purpose base class. The blank methods (like InitializeThread() in a thread encapsulation) allows me to optionally extend the base class, but I would never write code in the base methods and never call base.

Calling base is just wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @Holstebroe and @Bruno Costa. When you are explicitly calling base.Method every time, you are effectively cutting off the potential for polymorphism, and that's one of the basic reasons to use inheritance in the first place.